# Adding CSS width in an HTML object tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<style>
#window1 {
    width: 100%;
    border: solid;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;

}

#window1 object {
    width: 100%;

}
</style>

<script>
function load() {
    document.getElementById("window1").innerHTML='<object 
    width="100%" type="text/html" data="http://www.example.com"></object>';
}
</script>
```

What I'm trying to do is relaod the page www.example.com in a certain width, but I can't modify the width of the page www.example.com with CSS. The reference  in w3schools says that I need to add width inside the  tag. But what I wanted is to set the width using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `style` attribute as

```
document.getElementById("window1").innerHTML='<object 
    style="width:100%" type="text/html" data="http://www.example.com"></object>'
```